# SQLite Error: no such colum ListView on Click

Tags: android, sql

I'm currently working on an App with a listview. If I add an item to the listview it gets saved into an SQL Database (works fine). I wanted to use an OnLongClickListener to delete an item from the database but when I long-click an item of the listview I get the following error:

no such column: ID2 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT ID2 FROM people_table2 WHERE name2 = 'w'

The error occurs at the in this line:

> Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);

(getItem() method in the SQL) & in this line:

> Cursor data = mydb.getItemID2(name);

I am kind of confused since all these works without an issue in another activity (the only difference is that I open another activity instead of trying to open a popup window)

```
  ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id) {
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Cursor data = mydb.getItemID2(name);
                int itemID = -1;
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);

                }
                if (itemID > -1) {
                    Log.d("", "Die Rezept ID ist: " + itemID);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


               mydb.deleteName2(itemID, name);
               rezepteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

SQL:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "people_table2";
private static final String COL3 = "ID2";
private static final String COL4 = "name2";



public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME2, null, 1);


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL4+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean addData2(String item) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL4, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME2);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



public Cursor getData2() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2;
    System.out.println(TABLE_NAME2);
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}


public Cursor getItemID2(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME2 +
            " WHERE " + COL4 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}



public void updateName2(String newName, int id, String oldName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " SET " + COL4 +
            " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL3 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL4 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}



public void deleteName2(int id, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME2 + " WHERE "
            + COL3 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL4 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);

    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);

}
```

Hopefully, you can help me :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your table you are doing

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COL4+" TEXT)";
```

Specifically

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

Should be

```
ID2 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

to match your

```
private static final String COL3 = "ID2";
```

Don't forget to reinstall the app to reflect changes.

Comment: It works now, thank you. Really appreciate your help! :)

I actually did this already but I didn't reinstall my app (since my lack of sql knowledge).